# Eloquent query scope on relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models called `Page` and `User` and I've set up the Eloquent relation as follows:

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('User')
}
```

When I `dd(Page::with('user')->get())` I get the right result. But now I want to have a search filter on  this result.

I've used a `scopeSearch` but I'm not sure how to search on the resultset.

At the moment I have a scope like this:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search) {
  $query->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
     ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
}
```

So when I `Page::with('user')->search('Test')->get()` it is not working.
The problem (probably) is that the `username` column is part of the `User` table and the `name` is part of the `Page` table.

How would I be able to use a scope or something familiar, to search on the resultset, without repeating it in most of the queries?

Comment: Change those single quotes around `%$search%` to double quotes..

Comment: Sorry I've updated it, forgot it @JonathanCrowe. This is not the problem though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create `scopeSearch` in `User` model and you should use it this way:

```
$posts = Page::with('user')->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($search)
{
    $q->search($search);

})->get();
```

Comment: How would I be able to orderBy an column from the relation. I've just used a `::join` now instead of eager loading cause I haven't found out yet. For example I want to orderBy a page column or user column.

Comment: If you have new question, you should ask one as separate question